# Why didn't Paul talk to Peter privately?

Tags: matthew, contradiction, galatians

In Galatians 2 Paul describes a time when he rebuked Peter (Cephas) publicly:

> Galatians 2:11-14 (NIV): When Cephas came to Antioch, I opposed him to
> his face, because he stood condemned. For before certain men came
> from James, he used to eat with the Gentiles. But when they arrived,
> he began to draw back and separate himself from the Gentiles because
> he was afraid of those who belonged to the circumcision group. The
> other Jews joined him in his hypocrisy, so that by their hypocrisy
> even Barnabas was led astray.
>
> When I saw that they were not acting in line with the truth of the
> gospel, I said to Cephas in front of them all, “You are a Jew, yet you
> live like a Gentile and not like a Jew. How is it, then, that you
> force Gentiles to follow Jewish customs?

But Jesus told us in Matthew 18 that we should first confront a fellow believer privately, and only expose the sin publicly if they won't repent.

> Matthew 18:15-17 (NIV): If your brother or sister
> sins, go and point out their fault, just between the two of you. If
> they listen to you, you have won them over. But if they will not listen, take one or two others along, so that ‘every matter may be established by the testimony of two or three witnesses.’ If they still refuse to listen, tell it to the church; and if they refuse to listen even to the church, treat them as you would a pagan or a tax collector.

Is there anything in either of these passages that would explain why Paul thought it was acceptable to start with a public rebuke?

Comment: @ curiousdannii, I put "according to the Calvinist". I hope the question is ok now.

Comment: Please quote all the verses you reference so that we can more easily understand the context. And can you explain the relevance of this question to Calvinism?

Comment: how do you know that he didn't?

Comment: The verse says "When I saw that **they** were not acting in line with the truth of the gospel, I said to [Peter] in front of them all..." In other words he is not just rebuking Peter, but the entire group that are sinning, and those are the people who are there.

Comment: @DJClayworth, can you please explain me how _he is not just rebuking Peter_ ? When it read _I opposed **him** to **his** face, because **he** stood condemned_  ---> Not "them"/"their"/"they" .... _I said to **Cephas**_ ---> Not "them"..... _**You** are a Jew_, so the "you" here is Peter, not you in plural.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, do you mean before that event, Paul already talked with Peter privately about the future event ?

Comment: @curiousdannii, I've quoted the verse. You wrote : _"can you explain the relevance of this question to Calvinism?"_. I'm sorry as I don't have an  explanation of that. I put "to the Calvinist" is to follow _They must be edited to ask for **one perspective**_. When my question before is without "to the Calvinist", I thought my question goes to : _ask for an overview of all Christian positions_.

Comment: @karma Assuming the translators have done their job correctly, "them all" would be the same as the "they" that are not acting in line with the truth. In other words, the people present with Paul are the people who are sinning. His actual words are to Peter, but it's words that the other people need to hear because they know the same applies to them. I'm not guaranteeing that is the way it happened, but it's a plausible explanation and it would be in line with what Paul writes elsewhere, and thus remove any question of "why didn't Paul do this privately?".

Comment: @karma You still should add the quote of the verses from Galatians. If you don't know the significance to Calvinism, if you're just picking a position at random, then I think it would be better to ask about these verses at [hermeneutics.se]. I can migrate it for you if you would like?

Comment: You have done it again; you have assumed a fact in the asking of the question? On what basis do you assert that they did not also confer privately?  Scripture isn't a 24/7 transcript of each moment of their lives.

Comment: @curiousdannii, I'm sorry I forget to quote Galatian verse, I will quote the Galatian verse, curiousdannii. And yes, actually I just  picking a position at random just to comply the _"They must be edited to ask for one perspective"_. And if you think that my question is more suitable in Biblical Hermeneutics, I'd be thankful if you can migrate it.

Comment: @DJClayworth, you wrote : "it's a plausible explanation and it would be in line with what **Paul writes elsewhere**". Would you please tell me on what verse ?

Comment: @korvinstarmast, I'm sorry I don't understand about your question "On what basis do you assert that they did not also confer privately?". On 1-Jan-2020 10.00 am, I see Mr.Smith ride his motorbike while he has the option to ride his car. So I ask "why Mr. Smith didn't drive his car today at this 10 am time ?". How come the comment is _"on what basis do you assert that Mr. Smith did not also drive his car before today or after today? He doesn't need to report every moment of his life"_. And in your first comment : "how do you know that he didn't?", what do you meant by that question ?

Comment: This is pretty basic stuff.  *have you stopped beating your wife?*  is the example often used for a badly constructed questoin wherein an assumption is embedded in the structure of a question.  Your assumption is unsupported, so I suggest that you re-form your question without that assumption embedded in it.  Scripture in this case told us a thing that someone did do, but it does not tell us what they didn't do, or might have done, or might not have done.  Conferring privately may or may not have taken place. yet you assert without support that it did not.

Comment: Sorry for forgetting about this. I've edited the question, and will migrate it. But I edited it down to the base question, if you have questions about differences between translations, ask them separately at [hermeneutics.se].

Comment: @KorvinStarmast, I don't understand why my question is an assumption. As my illustration, when I see that Mr.X ride a motorbike then ask "Why didn't Mr.X drive his car?" How come that question is an assumption ? So at the time of the event, if for example just right after Paul oppose Peter then **Peter respond : _"Paul, why didn't you talk to me privately?"_** , I don't understand why did you say that Peter's question is  a badly constructed question wherein an assumption is embedded in the structure of his question ?

Comment: @curiousdannii, thank you for migrating my question here and thank you also for editing my question.

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious Paul the apostle didn't speak to the apostle Peter beforehand about this future. Matthew 18:15 reads "if your brother sins **against you**, go, reprove him between you and him alone. If he hears you, you have gained your brother." This wasn't a business or personal offense against Paul, alone. But rather concerned the truth of the good news.

This wasn't Peter's hidden or private act, but his public Judaizing. It wasn't only acceptable, but "necessary" that Paul did this. Referring to others in a slightly different context: "To them we yielded with the subjection demanded not even for an hour, that the truth of the gospel might remain with you." Galatians 2:5.

(In Acts 16:37 in a legal and physical context, with (unbelieving) authorities: "Paul said to them, They have beaten us publicly, uncondemned, men who are Romans, and have thrown us into prison; and now secretly they are thrusting us out? No indeed! But let them come themselves and bring us out.")

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Walter. I'm sorry, I don't understand what do you mean on _"his public Judaizing"_ ? That time in Paul's mind, Peter is afraid of those who belonged to the circumcision group which causing Peter to separate himself from the Gentiles. How come Peter's one time act like at that time means _"Peter is Judaizing the whole Gentiles there publicly"_ ?

Comment: _Matthew 18:15 reads "if your brother sins **against you**..."_. As curiousdannii suggested, I probably will make another question as the Mat 18:15 I quoted in this question has no **against you**, Walter. Thanks.

Comment: a) it **was** public. b) Paul pointed out Peter's hypocrisy which was in the form of Judaizing. And attributing to him the same guilt as the "James party" of putting [ceremonial] law on the Gentile saints. c) Peter was a **notable** in that he was an original disciple and an apostle who took the lead in speaking at Pentecost and Cornelius' home, and probably a leader in the assembly in Jerusalem. d) This was **after** the matter had ostensibly been settled in Acts 15 and 11. e) Again, it was an offense against the Truth, not against Paul alone. f) I understood that Mt's Greek has "against you"

Comment: Walter, You wrote : _"Paul pointed out **Peter's hypocrisy**"_ , What still I don't understand is : "how a ONE TIME act **because afraid of something = hypocrisy**" ? How did Paul _when he saw Peter ONE TIME act which is separating himself from the Gentiles_ say that Peter's act at that time : **separating himself from the Gentiles = Peter is Judaizing everyone in that place** ?

Comment: Thanks for your kindness in asking. i'm honored. I answered the 'one time act' matter in my previous comment. If it's hidden, i'd love to make it very explicit. But first, please, if you want, or have time, could you comment ever so briefly how, even if this is only his one time act, it's **not** hypocrisy in your mind? Isn't a (first-time) act hypocrisy if it **contradicts** one's faith or previous faithful actions? (As far as 'everyone in that place,' I hope most present weren't Judaized by Peter or those from James, but it sounds like several were--whether consciously or 'unconciously.')

Comment: Hi Walter, in my opinion - it's not right to judge someone is a hypocrite just by seeing a one time act. For example illustration: many people (include Mr.Y here) know that Mr.X has a principle that one should not drive cars to make the environment better. Mr.Y always see that Mr.X ride a bicycle ... but one day Mr.Y saw a car passing by - which Mr.X is the driver. ---continue

Comment: (A) Mr Y directly judged that's hypocrisy. To me, Mr. Y has not the right to judge Mr.X like that. Let alone, Mr. Y THINK that (B) Mr.X drive a car is because  Mr.X is afraid that he will be late to bring his child, bleeding to death, to the hospital if he ride a bicycle .... yet Mr. Y still say that is hypocrisy.

Comment: You wrote : _"Isn't a (first-time) act hypocrisy if it contradicts one's faith or previous faithful actions?"_ . No to me. She need to know first at least a few times where the other person's act contradicts to what she know that it's his believe/principle. If for example my own father always taught me : "be honest to everyone, don't cheat, etc" ... but in everyday life I see a few times that my father lie to some people, he cheat some people... then I have the right to judge that my father is a hypocrite.---continue

Comment: On the other hand, one day I see my father lie to his boss --- which **I thought** that's because my father is afraid he will be unable to feed his family because the boss will fire him if he doesn't lie... then I don't feel that I have the right to judge my father is a hypocrite.

Comment: I wonder in a Christian world, for example there is a priest who in front of his congregation frequently say "don't beat your children". So, some people from the congregation see that this priest is very patient to his naughty children... he never beat his children while in these congregation people's mind _"I will slap if my child naughty like his child"_. But one day, he see the priest slap his child. So, in the point of view of Christianity : the congregation has the right to judge the priest is a hypocrite ? The congregation don't need to know WHY the priest slap his child **that time** ?

Comment: Another example: Mr.X frequently say to his Christian neighbor that _"when go out, one must wear a mask during this pandemic to consider other people's health"_. So, from January to June this Christian neighbor see Mr.X always wear a mask when out. Until one day, July 1st - Mr.X found out that his mask is kaput by his dog. So without wearing a mask, Mr.X go out to buy a new mask. The Christian neighbor, for the very first time, on that July 1st, see Mr.X go out without mask. Then yeah, this Christian neighbor is right to judge that is an act hypocrisy of Mr.X ?

Comment: Your original question was about public vs private. I feel that was answered because Mt 18 only concerns private sin (eg: "against you"). Separating Jewish and Gentile Christians is Judaizing and racism, just like separating blacks and whites is racism. Now maybe in some emergency, like persecution--to save one group--there would be a good reason. But in Galatians 2, in Antioch, where Paul lived and Peter was visiting, Paul knew and saw the bad reason: Peter's fear, unwarranted subservience, to James, Jesus' brother, from Jerusalem. Peter overcame fear twice before in this, in Acts 11 and 15.

Comment: You are right that my original question is about public vs private :). I'm planning to make another question about hypocrisy. Anyway to be honest, it seems the answer for the question is more by "outside" reason, since another version of Mt18 doesn't have "against you". _Separating Jewish and Gentile Christians_..., I can't see that Peter's separating himself from the Gentile surely that means it's based on Peter's intention to separate Jews and Gentile. _Peter's fear, unwarranted subservience_, isn't this an accusation without proof ? What's Peter's afraid of ? being beaten by James group?

Comment: The Greek has 'against you.' But if absent, it's implied. Peter's separation act = Judaizing. No one forced him. And, if ever he were forced physically, his duty would be to yield not. Apparently he feared (whether he was accurate about them or not) their condemnation or ostracization. It's his weakness. Thankfully, Paul helped him by condemning him the other way (Gal 2:11)! The sight was the proof. Maybe Paul had spiritual sight that we wouldn't have yet had. If you're a Republican eating with Democrats, than move when your Republican friends arrive, i'd witness your hypocrisy.

Answer (score 0):

**Why didn't Paul talk to Peter privately?**

In Galatians 2 Paul describes a time when he rebuked Peter (Cephas) publicly:

Galatians 2:11-14  (NIV)

Paul Opposes Cephas

> 11 "When Cephas came to Antioch, I opposed him to his face, because he
> stood condemned. 12 For before certain men came from James, he used to
> eat with the Gentiles. But when they arrived, he began to draw back
> and separate himself from the Gentiles because he was afraid of those
> who belonged to the circumcision group. 13 The other Jews joined him
> in his hypocrisy, so that by their hypocrisy even Barnabas was led
> astray."
>
> 14" When I saw that they were not acting in line with the truth of the
> gospel, I said to Cephas in front of them all, “You are a Jew, yet you
> live like a Gentile and not like a Jew. How is it, then, that you
> force Gentiles to follow Jewish customs?"

**They all needed correction.**

Peter was obviously ashamed to eat with the Gentile Christians in the presence of the Jewish Christians that arrived from Jerusalem. Instead of talking behind Peter's back, Paul stood up to Peter in front of them all. Why? Because "other Jews joined him in his hypocrisy, so that by their hypocrisy even Barnabas was led astray."(Vs 13) It is obvious that peer pressure made Peter and the others reject their Christian principles, it was a sin on the part of Peter and the others to cause a division in the Christian congregation, they all needed correction.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, Ozzie. In Paul's mind Peter is not ashamed to eat with the Gentile Christian, but _afraid of those who belonged to the circumcision group_.